# Fullcalendar V5: Custom filter for the events

Tags: filter, fullcalendar, render

I am new to FullCalendar and would like to know how to filter events. For example. by a date or location of a patient?

And how can I rerender the whole calendar?
The method calendar.render(); rendered/rerendered only just what is necessary as far as I have read in the doc?

Thanks for any help

Edit:

I generate the script in Java with a StringBuilder and fetch the events from the DB with a method.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        
        sb.append("document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {"
                    + "var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');"
                    + "var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { ");
    
        sb.append("expandRows: true, ");
        sb.append("nowIndicator: true, ");
        
        sb.append("slotMinTime: '06:00', ");
        sb.append("slotMaxTime: '21:00', ");
        
        sb.append("customButtons: { "
                    + "myCustomButton: { "
                    + "text: 'New Request', "
                    + "click: function() { "
                    + "var url = document.getElementById('createRequestUrlId').value;"
                    + "window.open(url,\"_self\");"
                    + "}"
                    + "}"
                    + "},");
        
        sb.append("headerToolbar: { "
                + "left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton', "
                + "center: 'title', "
                + "right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth,listMonth'"
                + "}, ");

        sb.append("initialDate: \'" + dateFormat(new NSTimestamp()) + "\', ");
        sb.append("navLinks: true, ");
//      sb.append("businessHours: true, ");
//      sb.append("editable: true, ");
        sb.append("selectable: true, ");
        sb.append("dayMaxEvents: true, ");
        
        sb.append("eventClick: function(arg) {"
                    + "var eId = arg.event.id; "
                    + "document.getElementById('dialogFieldEventId').value = eId;"
                    + "document.getElementById('submitButton').click();"
                    + "document.getElementById('eventOpenerId').click();"
                    + "}, ");
        
        sb.append("events: [ ");
    
        sb.append(eventList());
        sb.append("]"               
                + "});");

        sb.append("calendar.render();"); 

        sb.append("});");
```

This method is called once when the page/calendar is loaded and then not again unless I reload the page.
However, I only want to reload the calendar with, for example, the filtered events, which are filtered in a Java method.
But I don't know how to call the script again with my java method. If the method of Fullcalendar 'calendar.render()' is called again only the finished script from the beginning is called.

Which for example looks like this

```
...

events: [{
                            id: '4321',
                            title: 'Name',
                            color: '#6495ED',
                            start: '2021-04-11T15:00:00',
                            end: '2021-04-11T15:30:00'
                        }, {
                            id: '1234',
                            title: 'Name',
                            color: '#FF7F50',
                            start: '2021-04-12T15:00:00',
                            end: '2021-04-12T15:45:00'
                        }, {
                            id: '3124',
                            title: 'Name',
                            color: '#CB3312',
                            start: '2021-04-13T15:00:00',
                            end: '2021-04-13T20:00:00'

...
```

Comment: Normally you'd filter the event data using a SQL query (assuming that's where it comes from before it goes into fullCalendar). So you need to send the filter parameters as extra parameters to the server. Is there something specific you're stuck on?

Comment: Also regarding the re-rendering, it's a bit unclear what your issue / question is. Are you having a specific problem? What are you trying to achieve? Also this sounds separate to the issue about filtering - if so you should move it to a separate stackoverflow post, to avoid confusing or conflating the two problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance on using this site effectively, thanks.